# Generate class diagram for C# using EA

Tags: c#, uml, enterprise-architect

I am trying to generate class diagram using reverse engineering concept of Enterprise architect.
I have successfully imported files using the option 'import source directory'. Next how to generate class diagrams using these imported files?

Answer (score 0):

In the “Import Source Directory dialog” is an option “Create Logical Diagram for Each Package”. If you select this option, EA creates class diagrams automatically during the import of the source files. If you want custom class diagrams, create a new class diagram (right click on the view -> add diagram -> new class diagram) then simply drag and drop the files from the project browser to the editor.